# TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my program loads a list of users (with jsonplaceholder data) and I am trying to make this data editable, but gives an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

Can someone help?

```
class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      displayList: 'block',
      displayForm: 'none',
      edit: false,

      userEdit: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        email: "",
        address: {
          street: "",
          suite: "",
          city: "",
          zipcode: ""
        },
        phone: ""
      }
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsersList();
  }

  getUsersList(){ ... }

  getUserEdit(){ ... }

  handleClick(id){ ... }
```

I have difficulty making the code inside the handleChange function, possibly it could also be wrong

```
handleChange(event){
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({
      userEdit:{
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }

  render(){
    if (this.state.edit === false) {
      return (
        <UsersList
          users = {this.state.users}
          displayList = {this.state.displayList}
          handleClick = {this.handleClick}
        />
      );
    }

    else {
      this.getUserEdit();
      return(
        <UserEdit
          user = {this.state.userEdit}
          displayForm = {this.state.displayForm}
          handleChange = {this.handleChange}
          handleClick = {this.handleClick}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Inside UserEdit.js

```
function UserEdit(props){
  return(
    <ul>
      <div style={{display: props.displayForm.form}} key={props.user.id}>
        <form>
          <h2>{props.user.name} </h2>
          <p>Email:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              value = {props.user.email}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}
            />
          </p>
          <p>Address: </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Street:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="street"
                value = {props.user.address.street}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}
              />
            </li>
            <li>Suite:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="suite"
                value = {props.user.address.suite}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}
              />
            </li>
            <li>City:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="city"
                value = {props.user.address.city}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}
              />
            </li>
            <li>ZipCode:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="zipcode"
                value = {props.user.address.zipcode}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p>Phone:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="phone"
              value = {props.user.phone}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}
            />
          </p>
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => props.handleClick()}> Save </button>
        <hr></hr>
        </div>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether `address` contains `street` or not. On the same lines, you should also check whether `user` contains `address` or not.

One liner check could be as:

`value = { props.user && props.user.address && props.user.address.street ? props.user.address.street : '' }`

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: you can upvote the answer for newcomers on this question.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because `props.user.address` is `undefined` and you try to access `props.user.address.street`.

What you should do check it before using it.

```
value={props.user.address ? props.user.address.street : ''}
```

You should do that in other places that you have `props.user.address.something`.

Comment: Now it doesn't give the error, but I can't edit the inputs. When I click on the keyboard, it kind gives "refresh" in the form